# iOS PWA Background Audio Support

Tags: ios, audio, progressive-web-apps

While playing audio in Safari on iOS, it is possible to minimise Safari or lock the screen and the audio continues to play. However, if the site is installed to the HomeScreen as a PWA, minimising the PWA or locking the screen pauses the audio.

Is there any way to make playback continue in the background when in the iOS PWA?

The problem is described in detail here:
https://medium.com/prototyped/what-we-learned-about-pwas-and-audio-playback-10a01c6aecbd

Comment: My guess, is for now, since Apple is choosing to more or less disable media (audio and video) for homescreen apps I seriously doubt it. Hopefully they will fix this soon and we can all get on with our lives.

Comment: Background audio seems to work fine from PWA now -- though you can't update the artwork/controls on lock screen properly yet.

Comment: @ColinRicardo which iOS version are you testing on?

Comment: I'm testing on iOS 14

Comment: @Akd it seems here, that there's a difference between just adding to home screen and full PWA. For adding to home screen, background play works. For PWA, it does not.

Comment: Thanks @Colin for keeping updated. I guess by “just adding to home screen” you mean that a website that is not a PWA is added to the home screen as a shortcut. In this case upon tapping it opens in Safari rather than in a separate WebKit instance. According to my observation, websites opened in Safari are allowed to playback in the background, as opposed to installed PWA. I guess you mean the same.

Comment: @ChrisLove - that's a really interesting statement (because I'm building such an app). Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: this time last year that was true. The fixed the bug a few updates later

Comment: still true as of today (2021.09.29) - PWA won't work, just a safari-bookmark will.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been a bug fixed in iOS 15.4
https://twitter.com/othermaciej/status/1491500338305667072

I just tried it and it appears to work fine!

Answer (score 0):

As partial workaround for iOS - you can use this setting in manifest

> "display": "minimal-ui"

When user click pwa app icon on home screen the Safari is opened, as result pwa is opened like web-site with address bar in Safari and playback in the background is working

Answer (score -2):

**This is the best way to not stop playing audio files on iPhones**
Using this plugin you can play audio files in the background

Prevent display sleep and enable wake lock in all Android and iOS web browsers.

[NoSleep.js](https://%20https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js)

Comment: The question is about playback in the background from PWA, but the answer seems to be about preventing going to the background, thus irrelevant.